# what does "we can make sisters for life" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

ok, here is the exact saying that appeared in an American movie.

"**we can make sisters for life**"

I couldn't find the definition of "make sisters" on the internet.

so, I assumed that "make sisters" likes "make friends"

So, make sisters with somebody=become a sister of somebody

["for life" can mean "for the rest of someone's life"](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/life)

So, we can make sisters for life=we can become sisters of each other for the rest of our life.

**could I be right?**

Comment: Short Answer: Yes. Long Answer: As mike says in his answer below, it refers specifically to sorority sisters.

Comment: @TeacherKSH - Yes, a great example of why the O.P. should ***always*** include the title of the movie!

Comment: And I would say, "for the rest of our lives."

Answer (score 1):

If google serves, the line is from a movie called 'Neighbors 2: Sorority Rising'

> You know what we should do?
>
> We should start our own sorority. One that can party the way that we want to.
>
> Mmm-hmm.
>
> And like, most importantly, we can **make sisters for life**. Yeah!

A [sorority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraternities_and_sororities) is a society for female students in a university or college, typically for social purposes. They are prominent in the United States (often identified by Greek letters), and are frequently depicted in movies set in American universities as a result.

A sorority is often considered to be a [sisterhood](http://sisterhood) of sorts, and as a member of a sorority, it's commonplace to refer to your fellow members as **sorority sisters**, which is what your movie quote refers to.

Comment: what about "for life"? why don't say clearly "for the rest of our life" as we learned from textbooks

Comment: English is a living language, and whatever is prescribed in a textbook is only relevant for when the textbook was written -- and even then, it only represents a "safe" way of expressing yourself. But the users of English are perpetually testing the boundaries -- this is how language changes! So if "for life" expresses what you mean, and is understood by your listeners, why make the effort to say "for the rest of your life"? Let's face it, an English textbook will ALWAYS be out of date!

Comment: @Tom - The phrase _for life_ means what you suspected it means: for the rest of one's life. It's an [established idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+life).